# External link to Angular5 application redirects to default route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am having trouble understanding why an external link to my Angular application is redirecting to the default route page from a browser.

The application allows a user to enter someones email address in which the triggers an API which then emails the email address in question with a link to a page within the application which is 'external' facing. This page is not behind any authentication and the user should be allowed to access this page from the link in the email they received to complete the invitation sign up process.

The generated URL contains a key which is checked to be valid when the page is access in order to check that the user had received a valid invitation.

One thing I have noticed is that when I try and access the URL I get redirected to the default route page (login) but when I press enter again the application does not reload and it takes me to that page correctly. Entering the URl a third time will cause the application to reload again and redirecting to the default route, a 4th time it works, etc etc.

Here is an example of the generated external link to my application that gets sent to  a new user via email.

```
http://degould-login.dev/#/acceptinvite?key=e1061fd2-85de-42b9-89a0-ac8667bd1b84
```

Here is my routes file:

```
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./components/home/HomeComponent";
import {LoginComponent} from "./components/login/LoginComponent";
import {SearchVehicleComponent} from "./components/search/SearchVehicleComponent";
// Reports
import {ReportsDashboardComponent} from "./components/reports/ReportsDashboardComponent";
import {ReportExceptionsComponent} from "./components/reports/reportExceptions/ReportExceptionsComponent";
import {IndividualReportExceptionComponent} from "./components/reports/reportExceptions/IndividualReportExceptionsComponent";
import {ClaimReportsComponent} from "./components/reports/claimReports/ClaimReportsComponent";
import {BoothReportComponent} from "./components/reports/boothReports/BoothReportComponent";
import {UserReportComponent} from "./components/reports/userReports/UserReportComponent";
import {VehicleReportsComponent} from "./components/reports/vehicleReports/VehicleReportsComponent";
// Users
import {RegisterComponent} from "./components/users/registerComponent/RegisterComponent";
import {UsersDashboardComponent} from "./components/users/UsersDashboardComponent";
import {EditUserComponent} from "./components/users/editComponent/EditUserComponent";
import {SignupComponent} from "./components/users/signupComponent/SignupComponent";
import {ResetPasswordComponent} from "./components/users/resetPasswordComponent/ResetPassword.component";
// Guards
import {AuthGuard} from "./guards/AuthGuard";
import {SuperUserGuard} from "./guards/SuperUserGuard";
import {PublicGuard} from "./guards/PublicGuard";


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'acceptinvite', component: SignupComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [ PublicGuard ]},
    { path: 'forgottenpassword', component: ResetPasswordComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },

    // User Section
    { path: 'users', component: UsersDashboardComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'users/register-user', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'users/edit-user/:username', component: EditUserComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ], pathMatch: 'full' },

    /*{ path: 'users', component: UsersDashboardComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ],
        children: [
            { path: 'register-user', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ] },
            { path: 'edit-user/:user-to-account-id', component: EditUserComponent, canActivate: [ SuperUserGuard ] }
        ]
    },*/

    // Reports
    { path: 'reports', component: ReportsDashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'reports/report-exceptions', component: ReportExceptionsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'reports/report-exceptions/:report-exception-id', component: IndividualReportExceptionComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'reports/booth-reports', component: BoothReportComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'reports/claim-reports', component: ClaimReportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'reports/user-reports', component: UserReportComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'reports/vehicle-reports', component: VehicleReportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard, SuperUserGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },


    // Search
    { path: 'search/:search-term', component: SearchVehicleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'search', component: SearchVehicleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full' },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true });
```

The component that is supposed to be called ( I am just showing the relevant code):

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'signup',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/users/signup.component.html'
})

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('f') formDOM: any;
    @ViewChild(ShowHideInputDirective) input: ShowHideInputDirective;
    private key: string;
    private formDefaults: Object = {
        userGroups: [],
        accounts: []
    };

    private model: Object = {
        Name: '',
        Username: '',
        Email: '',
        Password: '',
        UserGroup: null,
        Account: null
    };
    loading:boolean = false;
    error = '';
    private showPass = false;

    constructor(
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _alertService: AlertService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _userService: UserService,
        private _authService: AuthenticationService,
        private _accountService: AccountService
    ) {
        this.key = _router.parseUrl(_router.url).queryParams["key"];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if(this._authService.isLogged()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/']);
        }

        this._userService.validateInviteKey(this.key)
            .subscribe((response) =>
```

And the component that gets loaded instead:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: '/app/views/login/login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    private model: any = {
        email: '',
        password: ''
    };
    private loading = false;
    private error = '';
    private resetPasswordUsername;
    private resetPasswordLoading: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private _alertService: AlertService,
        private _userService: UserService
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if(this._authenticationService.isLogged()) {
            this._router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        // reset login status
        //this._authenticationService.logout();
    }
```

My question why when trying to access a page of my application via a URL as shown above that isn't behind authentication do I get redirected to the login (default) page when the application is finished loading? Is it possible to do what I am doing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you import `RouterModule` with `useHash: true`?

Comment: Hi. Yes I do. I have added this to the question

Comment: You don't need `pathMatch: 'full'` when the path is not `''` (empty) or when the route has child routes.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure I understand how that would help me here though? thanks

Comment: I'd try without. If code that looks fine doesn't work, you need to be creative what you try ;-)

Comment: I added the pathMatch: full code to routes as I get an error otherwise. :)

Comment: I have added the full router to the original question

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and by setting:

```
initialNavigation: 'enabled'
```

In my RouterModule I solved it. Hope it helps.

https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#initialNavigation